# APP and DLL relying on some files: on which directory?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll

I am having some dll and some libraries which must be included in my Visual Studio application.

According to you, a part of the path C:\Windows where do I have include them to be recognised by the app, and meantime, by the dll?

Comment: Which files do they rely on? Windows internal or from an external party?

Comment: Impossible to answer. Lots of possible solutions. Cannot tell which is best. Writing anything to C:\Windows is absolutely wrong. Don't do it. That directory belongs to the system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not good to place something into c:\Windows unless you really have to (drivers and other low-level staff).

- If your product is single standalone app, you may place all the necessary files into the same folder
- If you plan to have several products (or at least several versions of the same app installed simultaneously), you may be interested in C:\Program Files\Common Files

P.S. And yeah, don't forget to use Win API functions to resolve special directory names (instead of hardcoded c:\windows etc)